# unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached when running JMETER

Tags: jmeter

i'm trying to run a load test with Jmeter on mac(linux).
i'm getting the following error:
JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached.

mtis-MBP-2:~ mti$ ulimit -a | grep processes
max user processes              (-u) 709

any suggestions?